# unexpected EOF while looking for matching

Tags: bash, shell

I am getting

> line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

error while running

```
docker exec -it cassandra-test bash -c "cqlsh -k KEYSPACE -u USER -p PASS -e \"COPY tablename TO 'tablename.csv' WITH HEADER=TRUE\""
```

command. I tried to play with the different variants of above mentioned symbols, but didn't succeed. What is the problem here?

Comment: I can't find a problem. I'd propose to prune the long command line until it succeeds, then stepwise add complexity.

Comment: I guess there's something else than `PASS` in the real code. Do you provide the password literally in the code or via a variable? How exactly? Does it contain `"`? Does it contain any character that means something in the shell syntax?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes, I provide real password instead of PASS but it is just a word - without any special characters.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I provide it just as a text  - variables aren't used.

Comment: I wonder if it's docker mangling that command line somehow. It probably shouldn't, since the manual says `docker exec sh -c "echo a && echo b"` should be ok, while `docker exec "echo a && echo b"` would not work. But you could try to see what bash actually gets, try e.g. with the `-v` option: `docker exec -it cassandra-test bash -v -c "..."`  or with `printf` instead of bash: `docker exec -it cassandra-test printf "<%s>\n" bash -c "..."`

Comment: @ilkkachu the problem was that I was running the command with "bash" mentioned in the command, but meantime doing it from the windows' "PowerShell". I switched to Git bash and it worked.

Comment: @DavidHovsepyan, ugh. ok, I have no idea about how Powershell deals with quotes, but I can believe it'd do it differently from sh-like shells.